how to slide text using drawtext and ffmpeg
I am using ffmpeg drawtext to write text on a video between certain time duration. This is working fine but I was hoping if there is a way to slide the text from right of screen to desired x point instead of plain writing it. I also want the text to slide only for first one second during the given time period and then it remains stable for the rest of the duration.
So if my time duration is (t, 10, 15), then the text slides for first one second from right of screen to center of screen, and then remains on the screen for another 4 seconds. Likewise, if the duration is (t, 12, 25), then also the text slides for first one second (from right to center) and then remains stable for next 12 seconds and so on.
I know the x and y points where I want the text to appear, this I am calculating beforehand. The y part will remain constant, only the x point needs to change to make the slide effect of right to center. The video is 25fps, but this could change. The video is 900x1600 dimensions, but this could also change to 1280x720 or square etc.
Currently I am using below command to write the text:
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf " drawtext=fontfile=times.ttf:fontsize=35:fontcolor=white:box=0:text='Welcome to video':enable='between(t, 4, 10)':x=193:y=118 " -c:a copy -y out.mp4

If needed, I could separate the slide drawtext command, render it and then do a simple drawtext as soon as the slide effect ends, like this:

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf " drawtext=fontfile=times.ttf:fontsize=35:fontcolor=white:box=0:text='Welcome to video':enable='between(t, 4, 5)': y=118: x=something, drawtext=fontfile=times.ttf:fontsize=35:fontcolor=white:box=0:text='Welcome to video':enable='between(t, 5, 10)':y=118:x=193 " -c:a copy -y out.mp4


You have to basically use two drawtext filters one that moves and one that stands still.
For example:
ffplay -f lavfi -i "color=color=blue:s=800x400,drawtext=text='My text':fontsize=44:font='arial black':fontcolor=white:x=(W-tw)-t*((W-tw)/2)/1:y=(H-th)/2:enable='between(t,0,1)',drawtext=text='My text':fontsize=44:font='arial black':fontcolor=white:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:enable='between(t,1,15)'"

W = Main Video Width
tw = Text Width
H = Main Video Hight
th = Text Hight




Hi, what is "t" in "t*((" part? Is it current playtime in seconds/milliseconds, or is it total video length? Thanks

current playtime

Hi, @Ricardo Bohner I am accepting your answer. It does what I wanted. One more question, the current time is in seconds or milliseconds? And is there a similar variable for "current frame"? Thanks

@Smith Kumar yes "t" is the varible for current time. I don't know what you mean with specify the current time in milliseconds...but usually you can specify something like 0.200 for 200 milliseconds. You could also use frmes instead of current time for example x=(W-tw)-5*n would move the text 5 pixels to the left for each frame...

Hi @Ricardo Bohner is there a way to round up the "n" in this command? Problem is, as the video goes forward, the "n" value keeps increasing. So in a 30fps video, at 50 seconds, the value of n is 1500. This is bigger than the width dimension of the video itself 900x1600. So with "w-5n" the text is going off screen and simply disappearing instead of sliding. Can I do some math in the command to reduce the "n" to a single or a double digit number? Same problem is happening with "t" in "t((" part also.

@Smith Kumar the min() formula chooses the lowest of two values, so it will make the text stop at the middle. 30 represents the frame rate since you want to move the text in one second, If your frame rate is 30 and you would want the text to take 4 seconds to reach the middle you woud substitute 30 by 120 x=(W-tw)-'min((((W-tw)/2)/30*n),(W-tw)/2)':y=(H-th)/2"

You don't need two drawtext filters: use drawtext=...:x=(W-tw)-min(t,1)*((W-tw)/2)/1:y=(H-th)/2'

To slide text using drawtext in FFmpeg, use the x parameter to animate horizontal movement. For example:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Your Text':x='w-t*100':y=50" output.mp4


This slides the text leftwards across the video.

Hi, this is not what I actually want. I want the text to slide only for one second from right to left, reach my specified x point and remain there for next few seconds (whatever is specified in the duration).
